# Java JAR took High CPU Usage and Memory consumption

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu, protocol-buffers, cpu-usage

I am running a jar file on ubuntu system having 16 GB RAM. I used spring boot framework, JPA while developing the application.
I observed that memory and cpu usage keep on increasing after application started.

**What could be possible reason to constantly increase the CPU usage and memory ?**

What are operations is doing by application ->
 Update text file with

```
    File file = new File(file path);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile());
```

and read operation by

```
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream);
```

updating file with one min frequency.

I tried with run the jar as well as deploy war file on tomcat server in both cases its behaving same.

The main intension is to create proto-buffer text file. I have added

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public String generateProtoBuf(){
...
}
```

so every min this method will trigger and update the text file.

I exposed another API.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/getProtoBuf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getProtoBuf() throws IOException {
...
}
```

this API will call every twice in min.
file size will be less than 1 MB.

For initial few hours app is running normally but after few hour when cpu usage increase by 15% then It will drastically increase and touches 100% .

Comment: Do the files persist in memory after being loaded or are they garbage collected?

Comment: Those shouldn't have any impact on the performance.
Tried profiling the application?

Comment: JViusualM comes with SDK.

Comment: @jalako  I am not storing file in memory , file are updating at some location periodically.

Comment: @Buffalo I tried to profiling application but couldn't get root cause to increase memory and CPU usage.

Comment: @Antoniossss I will try JViusualM and explore it

Answer (score 0):

In your case, creating and (automatically) garbage collecting big object can cause a higher cpu usage, than working with less big objects. Also, when having a bad I-O performance, it can also slow `higher` your CPU usage, when having heavy I-O operations.

But mostly unperformant code will cause a high CPU usage. Check your code, or find the bottlenecks with a Java profiler. I can recomment [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/), since it is free and easy to use. But there are many other tools, which achieve the same result. When running your application with the profiler, you will see the functions/methods, which cause the high CPU usage.

Comment: I totally agree with your value able comment. I am guessing the same "garbage collecting big object can cause a higher cpu usage" . Thanks for https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/ component definitely ,It will help me to identify exact root cause.

Comment: Great to hear that! Feel free to upvote, if it helped to solve your problem.

Comment: sure , I will do it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to a find a thread that hogging CPU; you can do that with  [Arthas](https://github.com/alibaba/arthas) open source tool from Alibaba

Comment: Thanks for your comment,I found multiple thread are running at same time .When I started application on the same time I could locate multiple pids in htop command with same application name. Now out of those all pids only top most showing the high cpu usage and common thing all pids consuming equal memory%